# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Base Controller Get Current User expires

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

we have an asp.net core MVC app hosted in IIS with Windows Authentication and we have a base class on the controllers where we get the authenticated user, but sometimes when doing AJAX posts, it returns NULL, is this the right place to get the user? I suspect it is because of inactivity, but we had this problem happen only after 7 minutes of inactivity, thanks!

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public BaseController(IOptions<AppSettings> app_settings, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        ShortName = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspecting `contextAccessor` under a debugger should tell you what is going on.

Comment: Do you have any further questions to my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744867/understanding-calculus-by-correlating-time-distance-with-speed/2745059#2745059)? If not, then it would be nice if you accepted it.

Comment: I thought I deleted the question, the problem turned out to be something else, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you won´t accept it?

Comment: ohhh lol, you are asking me to accept the answer to another question in the calculus section, lol. will do, thanks